# Views table doesn't set fields next to each other

Tags: 7, views, theming

I got a content type with 7 fields. Each field can contain unlimited inputs. Like:

- Field Type/DN got fields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
- Field L got fields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

When I make this in a view table I get this:

```
Type/DN       L 
1             1
1             2
1             3
1             4
1             5
1             6
1             7
1             8
1             9
1             10
1             11
2             1
2             2
2             3
2             4
2             5
2             6
ETC.
```

What I want is

```
Type/DN       L
1             1
2             2
3             3
```

The fields are imported from a CSV file by feeds importer.

Here some images to show my settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue and I just want to clarify when you are adding fields in views, are you selecting the delta of the field? As shown in the below
image there are 2 fields showing for field_image in which you should be choosing the first one. Just make sure you are not choosing the delta one. Which may cause field to be displayed in the order which you don't want. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r80y7.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r80y7.jpg)

Comment: I know but that isn't the issue. The problem is that he adds all the content form the second field to every content of the first field.

Comment: would you be able to share some screenshot that how are you adding fields to the views.

Comment: The thing is what he outputs is how the view works what i want is something different and i don't know how to do it. I want that the first cel of the table is the first field of the input, So you get 1 next to 1 en 2 next to 2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the excel import input all the fields.
And make a node for every row in the xls file, then i made a extra field with the product name in the xls file so every node could reconize on what tabel they had to add the rows.

bit messy with a lot of tables but the out put works.